Elastic Beanstak laravel custom domain
I hope someone can help me on this one:
i have a laravel app that is deployed into aws elastic beanstalk, everything works great but when I added a custom domain to it, the main route (dev.myapp.com) resolves normally with the environment content myapp.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com, but when accessing ev.myapp.com/login the css /build/assets/app-CrG2wnyX.js wont resolve and site is broken, however myapp.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/login works greate.
in the root i have a folder .platform>nginx>conf.d>elasticbeanstalk>location.conf with location /
{
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}


i set APP_URL and APP_DOMAIN with dev.myapp.com
i also have in .platform>nginx>conf.d my-vhost.com with
server {
     listen 80;
     listen [::]:80;
     server_name dev.myapp.com www.dev.myapp.com;

     root /var/www/html/public;

     index index.php index.html index.htm;

     location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
     }

     location ~ \.php$ {
         try_files $uri =404;
         fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
         fastcgi_index            index.php;
         include                  /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
         fastcgi_pass             unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
         fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
         fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     }
}

server {
     listen 443;
     listen [::]:443;
     server_name dev.myapp.com www.dev.myapp.com;

     root /var/www/html/public;

     index index.php index.html index.htm;

     location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
     }

     location ~ \.php$ {
         try_files $uri =404;
         fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
         fastcgi_index            index.php;
         include                  /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
         fastcgi_pass             unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
         fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
         fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     }
}

